# Task Local processing inside a node across multiple steps of a Flink Dataflow

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Task Local processing inside a node:

Is there a way in a Flink dataflow pipeline to ensure that the 1st step and 2nd step of the dataflow happen on the same local Task slot/ local machine ?

Use case:
Have a real-time video processing need where the image from the 1st step needs to be used locally on the same machine in the 2nd step ? This mitigates having to get the huge image from another node in the 2nd node (basic locality requirement from Hadoop days).
TaskManagers can store local state in-memory or on their local disk. How can I make JobManager route 2nd step to same Task Manager ? Is it based on .keyBy(sameKeyId) to push it to the same partition ?
Can I do something like this by .keyBy(..) to limit to 1 partition/shard and operate on the 2nd step in the same partition on the same Task manager where the image was stored in the 1st step ? Saw this example on a pluralsight course:

```
.partitionCustom(new Partitioner<Double>() {
                @Override
                public int partition(Double key, int numPartitions) {
                    return key.intValue() % numPartitions;
                }
            }, 1)
            .setParallelism(1)//can i have more than 1 here ?
            .mapPartition(new MapPartitionFunction<Tuple2<Long, Double>, Tuple2<Long, Double>>() {
                @Override
                public void mapPartition(Iterable<Tuple2<Long, Double>> values, Collector<Tuple2<Long, Double>> out) throws Exception {
                    Iterator<Tuple2<Long, Double>> iter = values.iterator();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10 && iter.hasNext(); i++) {
                        out.collect(iter.next());
                    }
                }
            })
            .setParallelism(1)
```

TIA

Comment: I think officially there are no guarantees that can be made. In principal as long as it's a "forward" operation in the same vertex in the job graph (can be seen in the UI), then it's likely on the same task manager. I don't know that any guarantees are made about two separate keyBy operations going to different operators.

Comment: @Joshua - thx for your reply. Updated my question with the .partitionCustom question.

Comment: I don't think you need to set parallelism on the partitionCustom (I'm surprised it even lets you), and I believe you'd also be able to use just a normal `map` here rather than `mapPartition`. That all seed I think in principle it'd work